# Trying to Consolidate this code to use a Pandas Apply with a Unique ID

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
  
# Initialise data to lists.
data = [{'Filename': 'Filename 1', 'Grouping': 'NaN',  'Step': 1,  'Date': '6/09/2021'},
        {'Filename': 'Filename 2', 'Grouping': '1',    'Step': 2,  'Date': '6/09/2021'},
        {'Filename': 'Filename 3', 'Grouping': '1',    'Step': 2,  'Date': '6/09/2021'},
        {'Filename': 'Filename 4', 'Grouping': '2',    'Step': 1,  'Date': '6/10/2021'},
        {'Filename': 'Filename 5', 'Grouping': '2',    'Step': 1,  'Date': '6/10/2021'},
        {'Filename': 'Filename 6', 'Grouping': 'NaN',  'Step': 1,  'Date': '6/10/2021'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_1 = df[df['Grouping'] != "NaN"]
df_2 = df[df['Grouping'] == "NaN"]
df_1['id'] = df_1[['Grouping','Date']].sum(axis=1).map(hash)
df_2['id'] = df_2[['Filename', 'Step', 'Date']].sum(axis=1).map(hash)
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
```

Above is my current code, I am trying to make the unique ids generate using a one liner Pandas apply function with an if statement will read the grouping column and change the way the hash is generated if it has a "NaN" value.

Comment: is the unique ID just based on `'Grouping'` and then you want to label all the NaN with the same group ID?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do